# Which parts of an AC relay does the electrical current flow on?

Tags: relay, shock

Below is a common relay that is used in Arduino projects. When the AC lines are connected, if I touch the screws that holds the AC lines (marked as "1" in the image) do I get an electric shock? Of course, I am not going to intentionally do that, but just want to know. What if I touch the soldered pins at the bottom of the relay (marked as "2" in the image)? Do I get an electric shock?

[image]

Comment: Please don't build mains powered devices until you already have a thorough understanding of such things.  Learning is good, but you should gain a basic understanding working with low voltage systems before you consider a project such as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Yes, (2) Yes.  They are all connected.

If you are goung to be switching AC power, then you need to take appropriate precautions to make sure that nobody touches it.  That usually means putting the whole lot into an insulated or grounded box.

Comment: ... and screwing the board into a fixed position with spacers (insulating if required) so that the bottom side of the board can't touch the enclosure. Watch out for the chance of mounting screws touching live tracks on the board resulting in the exposed parts of the screws becoming live on the outside of the box.

Comment: Note that the voltage applied to the one of the three screws is connected to one of the other two when the relay is not energized by the driver and to the third screw when it is energized. You must be sure that you know which screw has each function.

Answer (score 0):

There are rules to switching AC mains power!  You just noticed the reason why.

### Enclosures

To start with, as Simon B discusses, you have to put it in an appropriate enclosure.  I know with low-voltage DC electronics, the habit is to play fast and loose with enclosures (read: not have any and just have spaghetti across the workbench).  *Not if you're touching mains AC power*.

A proper enclosure is either entirely plastic, or metal and tied to safety ground.  Any mains cable entry has a proper strain relief and grommet to keep the mains wires from fraying.

All mains electrical work is done inside one kind of junction box or another. Splices buried in walls are almost unheard of.

Common AC mains junction boxes are fine for electronics projects. Consider boxes such as the 4x4 drawn steel box ($1) (with various covers (30¢), or 4-11/16" (120mm) square deep boxes ($2-3).  These have "knockouts" that are easily popped out, and accept standard strain reliefs/grommets to fit cordage. ($2-4).  They also make gray waterproof plastic boxes that are designed to stand alone ($4) as well as aluminum waterproofs ($6); don't use blue boxes intended for mounting in walls.  All these are readily available at your local electrical supply; big-box stores sell them too at usurious cost.

### Grades of cord

Flexible cords used in an electronics project are proper SO, SJO, SJOW etc. types made for *cordage*; you never use in-wall wiring such as NM, UF, twin-and-earth etc.  (easiest way to get proper cordage: cut up extension cords).

You're welcome to use NM and other in-wall cables for low voltage electronic projects; #12 or #10 solid copper wire is a nice stiff "bus bar".  However solid wire is NOT made to be flexed repeatedly, and will metal fatigue, crack, heat and arc. The last two start fires.  That's why *cordage* is required.

### Physical separation

AC power has to be handled separately from low voltage wire - except for low voltage circuits that are entirely contained within Class 1 (AC power quality) wiring methods.   That's used, say, for fluorescent dimming or remote control light switches.  To put that another way, if low voltage wiring is in the same box or space as AC mains, then the low voltage wiring is "tainted" and must be entirely within Class 1 wiring and enclosures.

In other words, you are *planning* for the time AC power arcs internally on the board or to the relay coil, and throws 120V up your low voltage DC project.

That's the big problem with your little control board right there.  You need to put it inside an enclosure, but then, the low-voltage stuff will be inside the enclosure too, and presumably you're going to connect it to something *else* ... right?

There's one big exception to the separation rule: Fiber. If your fiber does not conduct electricity, it can mingle with AC power lines all it pleases.  I wish somebody would build one of those relay boards that takes a fiber connection from an Arduino!  Then the board could sit inside the enclosure and the fiber could come out to talk to your Arduino/tablet/PC/wherever you are going with it.

Bluetooth and WiFi also comply with the separation rule. You can use a metal junction box with a plastic cover if you want WiFi/Bluetooth transparency.

Comment: That's too much complex work for people other than electricians. I wish some company would sell the whole thing you explained as a single stand-alone unit that can be directly controlled with Arduino, without using a proprietary app from the manufacturer.

Comment: @DamnVegetables ABSOLUTELY!  I couldn't agree more.  What the world needs is a UL-listed switch (half the size of a pack of gum) that sits inside a junction box, and has 1 fiber-optic input.  Light on fiber = switch on.  Nothing to it but a photocell and a triac :)  It could also be done wired, replaces a junction box cover - DC screws on the outside, mains pigtails on the inside.  The DC side could take a dog's breakfast anything from 24VAC to 3.3VDC.  The trick is, design for UL approval from day 1...